# Handle errors or inconsistencies when parsing JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

The JSON response I'm trying to parse contains errors, but is out of my control. Specifically, a field which should normally be a number, is **sometimes** returned as an array, similar to this:

```
{ "myarray" : [
  { "myfield" : 1,   /*etc*/ }, 
  { "myfield" : [1], /*etc*/ },
  /* etc */
] }
```

Is there a way within JSON.NET to handle these kinds of special cases? Else I'll settle with a good old search and replace within the string before parsing.